# getDisplayMedia application window with audio?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, get-display-media

Currently the new getDisplayMedia() API only allows you to capture audio if using Desktop Capture or Chrome Window Capture.  Application window capture does not capture audio.

Is there a way to capture the full desktop audio when using Application window capture?  Not just microphone. Perhaps via work around then muxing together the audio and video track?